# column names of multiple data into a dataframe in R

Tags: r

Assume I have 3-data such as `iris`, `CO2` and `Formaldehyde`. I want the column names of all data into a `data.frame`. What is the easiest way of doing this? Desired output:

```
Iris                  Co2         Formaldehyde
Sepal.Length         Plant           carb
Sepal.Width          Type            optden
Petal.Length         Treatment        NA
Petal.Width          conc             NA
Species              uptake           NA
```

Comment: data.frame(iris_names = names(iris))?

Answer (score 3):

Say that you have all the data frames in a `list`:

```
mylist<-list(Iris=iris,Co2=CO2,Formaldehyde=Formaldehyde)
```

You can try:

```
data.frame(lapply(mylist,function(x) 
          `length<-`(colnames(x),max(lengths(mylist)))))
#          Iris       Co2 Formaldehyde
#1 Sepal.Length     Plant         carb
#2  Sepal.Width      Type       optden
#3 Petal.Length Treatment         <NA>
#4  Petal.Width      conc         <NA>
#5      Species    uptake         <NA>
```

Comment: What if I have 100-tables and want to collate like above. It is not feasible to do it by naming it. Please help me doing this using for-loop or by any best possible way.

Comment: How this 100 tables are stored? Each table is a different object? How are these objects named, if that's the case?

Comment: Actually more than 100-tables are in teradata for which I am trying to do the above task. Please look into my other request, probably you may understand clearly[Follow this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303850/column-names-of-multiple-teradata-dataframes-using-for-loop-in-r-teradatar)

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this with `stri_list2matrix`

```
library(stringi)
as.data.frame(stri_list2matrix(lapply(mylist, colnames)))
```

#### data

```
mylist<-list(Iris=iris,Co2=CO2,Formaldehyde=Formaldehyde)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `cbind.fill` from `rowr` package

```
cbind.fill(Iris=colnames(iris),Co2=colnames(CO2),Formaldehyde=colnames(Formaldehyde), fill = NA)

#      Iris         Co2    Formaldehyde
#1 Sepal.Length     Plant         carb
#2  Sepal.Width      Type       optden
#3 Petal.Length Treatment         <NA>
#4  Petal.Width      conc         <NA>
#5      Species    uptake         <NA>
```